# Normalization for model comparisons

Tags: macroeconomics, optimization, time-series, markov-chain

I have a time series applying the Markov Switching model, which is estimated in about 15 different versions. One or two of the time series had to be normalized in order to converge. That is 1-2 out of 15. My question is if I have to normalize all models in order to be able to compare and derive conclusions on the model's combination. For example, common pattern /behavior or is it fine to just normalize the non converging series but make sure it stated that results for them should be seen under the normalization. How much will I loose from the normalize - non normalize series? What are the best practices here